# MS Access Adding a Filtering ToolBar to Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

I have Microsoft Access Form where I have table of data I want to be able to add a filtering toolbar to the form in MBE mode.  Note MBE not in the designer mode of MDB.   I.e. I want a filter on the distributed MBE file.

In Form.Open event I  added:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
  DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarYes
  DoCmd.ShowToolbar "ribbonMain", acToolbarYes
  DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Menu Bar", acToolbarYes

End Sub
```

I also tried

```
Private Sub Ctl__Click()
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim prop As DAO.Property
  Set db = CurrentDb()
  DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarYes
End Sub
```

Also, Access Button - > Access Opiton ->Current Database
Under the Ribbon and Toolbar Options:
Checked Allowed Built-in Toolbars. Also, Ribbon Name is "ribbonMain".

I still cannot see the Toolbar in the top of Form.  What am I missing in the code or access page set up.  I am running on MS Access 2003.  I would really like to have same filtering you see in design mode of a table in an deployed MBE file.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting the code in the `On load` even instead also `DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarYes` may cause error in access 2003. When i was building my database i found this post helpful.
http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=97578